# Loop length java programming

Tags: java, loops

i have this assignment on school. They want me to create a blasttable, from 32 to -31, in the next piece of code i have the complete code, it works just fine. 
BUT, my teacher asks me if the length of the loop is correct, 
"Does the loops go to the right length?" 
In my opinion it does, but maybe there are some other solutions to this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] blastTable = new int [8][8]; 

    int counter = 32;

    for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < blastTable[0].length; j++) {
            blastTable[i][j] = counter;
            counter--;
        }
    }
    printArray(blastTable);
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void printArray(int[][] blastTable) { 

    String output = ""; 
    for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < blastTable[0].length; j++) {
                output += blastTable[i][j]+ " ";
        }
        output += "\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "BlastTable", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

}

Comment: You inner loops should use `blastTable[i].length`.

Comment: BTW: If you use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), you can achieve a better performance.

Comment: @brso05 The loops will go from 32 to -31. 8*8 is 64, so there will be 64 values. 32 to -32 is 65 values, counting 0...

Comment: I've tried to use blastTable[i].length, it works, but my teacher still asks the same question.. That question is driving me crazy..